# Stata: Saving to a specific folder

Tags: stata

I would like to save my outputs to a folder with the date of the analysis. My code looks like this

```
local d = c(current_date)
cd "c\RA-outputs"
mkdir "`d'"

twoway bar weeksum week
graph export "c\RA-outputs\`d'\out1.png", as(png) replace
```

However when I run this code I get an error saying the folder is not available. I know I'm making a some small mistake because I see the folder that has been created by the first three lines of code.

Comment: You are encouraged to not use backslashes here. See http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0042.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you say cd you need to point to a hard drive directory:

```
cd C:\
```

then mkdir

```
mkdir "`directory ' "
```

then save

```
save "C:/`name'\current_data.dta"
```

be careful the last slash is / not \ ...

Comment: My bad this was a typo.  I'm using the correct syntax in my actual code. And as I mentioned I see that the code creates a code a folder with the date as the folder name. I suspect the problem is in the path I use for the graph export.